# Open custom file extension from google drive on android

Tags: android, mime-types, google-drive-api

I am struggling with how to make a custom file extension open in my android application through the google  drive ui.  My file currently opens fine through dropbox or the android file explorer. Google drive seems to only consider the mime type of the file. The file extension is my own (lets say .xyz) and the file  is xml on the inside. I  want the file to open in my app not  just any app registered to open text/xml mime types. How can i tell google drive the .xyz files are not  to be treated like text/xml. Similarly i don't want my app to be registered to open all text/xml files.

So the end user workflow would be this:
1) Open Google Drive android app.
2) Tap "somefile.xyz" -> The file would be opened in my app. Currently it opens in the google drive xml viewer.
3) Tap "otherfile.xml" -> The file would not be opened in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this question is you can't do that.

With a file called .xyz and a format of xml on the inside the best you can do is to create various intent filters to handle all the ways other apps identify the file. For Example I put the following mimeTypes in my intent filters.

- Google Drive - text/xml
- ICS Gmail - text/plain
- JellyBean Gmail - application/octet-stream

Comment: I'm having the same problem getting a custom file to be recognized by my app from Drive and I'm not able to get your answer to work for me. Would you be able to share a full example of the intent filter you used? Thanks if you can!

Comment: Hi @Nathan: Can you explain it with Some example? I am struggling with above problem in my app. I want to get the extension of the file name which is shared via Google drive to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your files to the private directory of your application then it will not be accessed by any other app

See through this link how to do that

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Context.MODE_PRIVATE and getFilesDir() can be helpful to you.

Or if you want other apps to do something for you and return the result to your application 
Go through with this.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

or

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: I want to let the user manage their files through the various cloud apps. My app does not create files it simply opens existing files. My question is how do I make google drive open the .xyz file in my app.

Comment: Updated my post. I don't want my app to do something, the other app needs to see that my app is supposed to open .xyz files.

Comment: see now. If this doesn't help. My hands are Up

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help. I have implemented intent filters already in my app's manifest. That is why the file opens in my app when it is tapped through android's file browser or through the dropbox app. I get how intent filters work, I just can't figure out how to make google drive work.